Merge an extracted type back into discriminated union
So I have the following type A, descriminated by the property 'type':
type A = { type: 'x', foo: boolean } | { type: 'y', bar: string }

with this type I can make objects such as
{
  type: 'x',
  foo: false
}

or 

{ 
  type: 'y',
  bar: "hmm"
}

and I have a type B, which takes the { type: 'x' } discriminated union from A, and allows for an extra baz
type B = Extract<A, { type: 'x' }> & { baz: number }

This type B will allow for objects such as
{
  type: 'x'
  foo: false,
  baz: 3
}

Now, I want to merge this B back into another type, that will basically overwrite the union discriminated by 'x' with the definition from B, but leave the original 'type: y' from A intact. So like

{
  type: 'x'
  foo: false,
  baz: 3
}

or 

{ 
  type: 'y',
  bar: "hmm"
}


You could achieve it with a bit more type arithmetic. You could first subtract { type: 'x' } from A using Exclude, and then union the new member B back to it.
type A = { type: 'x', foo: boolean } | { type: 'y', bar: string };

type B = Extract<A, { type: 'x' }> & { baz: number };

type ReplaceInDiscriminatedUnion<TUnion, TMember extends { type: unknown }> = Exclude<TUnion, Pick<TMember, 'type'> > | TMember;

type C = ReplaceInDiscriminatedUnion<A, B>;

// type C = {
//   type: 'y';
//   bar: string;
// } | B

TypeScript Playground

That's fantastic! Would it be possible to construct this ReplaceInDiscriminatedUnion in such a way that will accept a variable number of types as arguments?

You can pass a union as TMember, and all of them will be replaced. I hope that's what you are looking for. type C = ReplaceInDiscriminatedUnion<A, B1 | B2>;
